# For PhD: Software for Cross-Matching & Organizing Files & Recordings + Metadata

Tags: web-apps, database, file-management, cloud-storage

For my PhD I am accumulating thousands pdf and word documents from with lecture notes, transcriptions, powerpoint slides, and handouts.

I also have several thousand recordings of lectures & interviews.

I am searching for a software which would allow me to upload all of these, cross-match them, tag them, add metadata, and be able to search and organize them by date, location, audience, or topic.

Ideally, this software would enable the creation of composite objects made up of multiple recordings, documents, tags, and metadata. For example, a composite object could be a lecture a person gave in Argentina last May and it would include:

- A recording from the speaker's iPhone
- A recording from the sound system where the Spanish translation is
  more clear
- A recording of a French translation made recently
- A pdf document of the speaker's notes
- A pdf document of someone's transcription in English
- A pdf document of a machine-generated transcription in Spanish
- A brief summary
- Tags such as: Big Data, Twitter, MongoDB
- Metadata such as:

  - Delivered: May 15, 2022
  - Event: DataCrunch Conference
  - Audience: University Students

An added bonus would be the ability to have user accounts with different access permissions to view, download, and edit these listings.

Does such a software exist? I've been searching and searching and haven't found one. I used to write software, so worst case I could maybe make it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called Cloud Storage.

Some of the main providers are:

- Google Drive
- Microsoft OneDrive
- Dropbox
- Box

What they can do for you:

- You can upload any kind of file, PDF or recording
- There is a space for a comments for each file (I checked now on my OneDrive, check the other if they have)
- Tags are not supported but every document is parsed through OCR, this means that if the document contains words like Big Data, Twitter, MongoDB you will be able to find them by searching from the search bar.
- Every file has its own metadata. Audience? Never heard about this metadata but you can put that in the comment of the file.
- Ability share with different access permissions to view, download, and edit

Answer (score 0):

For tagging across documents check out liquid text

https://www.liquidtext.net/

Comment: It would improve your answer if you described some relevant features of it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After much search, I think ArchiveSpace comes fairly close to providing what I need. I can upload all these assets and create complex relationships between them. I'll be able to search, filter, and sort them based on metadata fields. I can also have multiple users maintain the records while regulating access permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Suggestion - you could improve your answer by posting more information on it including screenshots if applicable.